# What does the ”なの” in this sentence mean?

Tags: grammar, translation

> ここは、おすしがぜんぶ百円なの？

I've read somewhat a lot on "na no" and just came to the conclusion that is something used to end a sentence similar to desu, but used mainly with females. So I was just wondering if this was the case in my sentence. Also the "お" written before "sushi" is just a honorific prefix right? Or does it meaning something else / have another use in the sentence?

Comment: The "お" in "おすし" is called 美化語 which technically is not 敬語。For example, you can say both "先生へのお手紙" and "先生からのお手紙". And, you sometimes use 美化語 to create humble verbs. Some words have lexicalized 美化語 such as "お巡りさん", "お土産", and "お茶". Basically, 美化語 is not strictly 敬語。

Answer (score 1):

That なの or any other のだ forms indicate that information that's accompanied with it is one to complement existing context. (In sentences of statement, it functions as explanation of background for a preceding topic.)

In your example, it's probably used in a situation where you reconfirm it after your opponent said that all the sushi there are 100 yen, or so. That's why she is using an interrogative sentence with a のだ form.

Edit: For some reason, emphasizing なの is often considered a feminine factor in fiction but in reality it's equally used regardless of gender and even when men use it, it doesn't sound girly. Old textbooks might still teach that bias.

Answer (score 0):

なの means what you say. This なの is used as question. なの　can be used as both affirmative and question sentence.

お is a polite prefix. For example, お家、お店、お弁当. In addition ご is also a polite prefix like ご飯、ご家族.

Answer (score 0):

Very literally speaking, なの consists of a nominal adjective marker な and a nominalizer particle の. This sounds like a roundabout way to say 'is/ is something like', which makes it understandable that it is mainly used by females. When used in a question, the か is sometimes omitted.

Comment: "なの consists of **a nominal adjective marker な** and..." >> Is it not the 連体形 of the 助動詞「だ」?  「百円な寿司」とか言わないし・・・